# Insert new rows when item is added to another table SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers

have to tables. One dimension table with projects and one fact table with projects, value and a period(month).

Looking to add 12 new rows pr project ID into my fact table, when a new project is added to the dimension table. The 12 rows should be the next 12 months. (always the month following the current)

I know it should be a Create Trigger when new row added, that part is fine.
The issue I have is how to write a SQL statement that I can use with a trigger to make this work. I have tried some versions on INSERT INTO, but I'm not experienced enough to know have to write this statement.

example: project 2 has been added to dim table.

| project | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Then create a trigger that adds these 12 new rows in my facttable

| project | status | Period | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | B | 6/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 7/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 8/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 9/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 10/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 11/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 12/1/2021 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 1/1/2022 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 2/1/2022 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 3/1/2022 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 4/1/2022 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 5/1/2022 | NULL |

Any suggestions on how to write this statement?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
 --==== Test 'inserted' table
Declare @inserted Table (Project int, Status char(1));
 Insert Into @inserted (Project, Status)
 Values (1, 'A'), (2, 'B');

 --==== Test 'facttable'
Declare @factTable Table (Project int, Status char(1), Period date, Value varchar(50));

 --==== Example code for trigger
   With periods (Period)
     As (
 Select dateadd(month, p.num, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0))
   From (Values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12) ) As p(num)
        )
 Insert Into @factTable (Project, [Status], [Period], [Value])
 Select i.Project
      , i.[Status]
      , p.[Period]
      , Value = Null
   From periods                 p
  Cross Join @inserted          i;

 --==== Show resulting fact table
 Select *
   From @factTable;
```

The example code for trigger is the solution and assumes you won't have duplicate Project entries.  We don't have to generate the numbers using row_number - just use VALUES and specify 1 through 12.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to generate a list of numbers on the fly and then unconditionally join to the `inserted` table to generate your rows:

```
with months as (
    select top (12)  Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) as m from sys.sysobjects
)
select i.Project, i.Status,
  DateAdd(month,m,DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, GetDate()), 0)) as Period
from months join inserted i on 1=1
```

Comment: Instead of querying `sysobjects` unnecessarily, why not use `(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)...)`

Comment: Yes of course you could do that, I tend to use this just for mocking on the fly especially when it's more than a handful of digits - of course in a full solution I'd use neither, with a permanent numbers table available for such things.